# RESTKit: Fault not firing

Tags: core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20, fault

I can't get the fault to fire in Core Data

.m

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) RKObjectManager *objectManager;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

...

- (RKObjectManager *)setupObjectManager
{

    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:kRESTBaseUrl];
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc]initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    RKObjectManager *manager = [[RKObjectManager alloc]initWithHTTPClient:httpClient];
    [manager.HTTPClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
    [manager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
    [manager.HTTPClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
    [RKMIMETypeSerialization registeredMIMETypes];
    [RKObjectManager setSharedManager:manager];

    return [RKObjectManager sharedManager];

}

- (RKObjectManager *)getObjectManager
{
    self.objectManager = (!self.objectManager) ?  [self setupObjectManager] : self.objectManager;
    return self.objectManager;
}

- (void)getManagedObjectFromAppDelegate
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.objectManager = [self getObjectManager];

    self.objectManager.managedObjectStore = appDelegate.managedObjectStore;
    self.managedObjectContext = self.objectManager.managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;

}
```

I fetch for the `User` locally, and if not found, I then fetch the server.

Once a `User` is found, I set the label properties on the main queue, and that's where the app crashes as the fault never fires and everything is `nil`.

```
- (void)didFinishFindingUser:(NSString*)user withResults:(NSArray*)results
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (results.count > 0)
        {
            self.inviteUser = (User*)[results firstObject];
            [self setNameForUser:self.inviteUser];
        }
    });
}

- (void)setNameForUser:(User*)user
{
    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    NSLog(@"User.firstName %@", user.firstName);
    //Code here to configure the labels
    //This is where the App crashes as the values are coming as nil
}
```

Log:

```
2014-07-26 00:46:16.324 App[12455:60b] User.firstName (null)
(lldb) po user.managedObjectContext
 nil
(lldb) po user
<User: 0x1780ac5a0> (entity: User; id: 0xd000000000040008 <x-coredata://99A54059-0A51-402C-9633-B47843B6414B/User/p1> ; data: <fault>)

(lldb)
```

As you can see that I'm accessing a property via NSLog to fire the fault, but it's not firing.

```
[User managedObjectContext] == nil
```

What can I do to fire the fault and get access to properties?

**** UPDATE ****

I have narrowed down the problem to when I call the `main_queue`, the object is turning in to a fault without a context.

**CODE**

```
- (void)didFinishFindingUser:(NSString*)user withResults:(NSArray*)results
{
        if (results.count > 0)
        {
            self.inviteUser = (User*)[results firstObject];
            NSLog(@"***** Thread BEFORE main_queue: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
            NSLog(@"NewUser %@", self.inviteUser);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSLog(@"***** Thread AFTER main_queue: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
                NSLog(@"NewUser %@", self.inviteUser);
            [self setNameForUser:self.inviteUser];
            });

        }
}

- (void)setNameForUser:(User*)user
{

    NSString *firstInitial = user.firstName.length > 0 ? [user.firstName substringToIndex:kInitialIndex] : [kFirstNamePlaceholder substringToIndex:kInitialIndex];
    NSString *lastInitial = user.lastName.length > 0 ? [user.lastName substringToIndex:kInitialIndex] : [kLastNmaePlaceholder substringToIndex:kInitialIndex];

    self.labelInitials.text = [firstInitial stringByAppendingString:lastInitial];
    self.labelName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", user.firstName.length > 0 ? user.firstName : kFirstNamePlaceholder, user.lastName.length > 0 ? user.lastName : kLastNmaePlaceholder];
    self.labelUserID.text = [@"@" stringByAppendingString:user.userid];
}
```

**LOG:**

```
2014-07-27 06:01:03.197 App[24030:3d07] ***** Thread BEFORE main_queue: <NSThread: 0xd6b2750>{name = (null), num = 4}
2014-07-27 06:01:03.198 App[24030:3d07] User Context <NSManagedObjectContext: 0xdb9a380>
2014-07-27 06:01:03.198 App[24030:3d07] NewUser <User: 0xda83280> (entity: User; id: 0xda7c4f0 <x-coredata://5251395C-DDDC-424C-9372-EA8D883E0AE6/User/p1> ; data: {
    firstName = Lois;
    lastName = Lane;
    userid = "lois.lane";
})
2014-07-27 06:01:03.199 App[24030:3d07] ***** Thread BEFORE main_queue: <NSThread: 0xd6b2750>{name = (null), num = 4}
2014-07-27 06:01:03.199 App[24030:3d07] User Context <NSManagedObjectContext: 0xdb9a380>
2014-07-27 06:01:03.200 App[24030:3d07] NewUser <User: 0xda83280> (entity: User; id: 0xda7c4f0 <x-coredata://5251395C-DDDC-424C-9372-EA8D883E0AE6/User/p1> ; data: {
    firstName = Lois;
    lastName = Lane;
    userid = "lois.lane";
})
2014-07-27 06:01:03.201 App[24030:3d07] ***** Thread BEFORE main_queue: <NSThread: 0xd6b2750>{name = (null), num = 4}
2014-07-27 06:01:03.201 App[24030:3d07] User Context <NSManagedObjectContext: 0xdb9a380>
2014-07-27 06:01:03.201 App[24030:3d07] NewUser <User: 0xda83280> (entity: User; id: 0xda7c4f0 <x-coredata://5251395C-DDDC-424C-9372-EA8D883E0AE6/User/p1> ; data: {
    firstName = Lois;
    lastName = Lane;
    userid = "lois.lane";
})
2014-07-27 06:01:03.203 App[24030:3d07] ***** Thread BEFORE main_queue: <NSThread: 0xd6b2750>{name = (null), num = 4}
2014-07-27 06:01:03.203 App[24030:3d07] User Context <NSManagedObjectContext: 0xdb9a380>
2014-07-27 06:01:03.203 App[24030:3d07] NewUser <User: 0xda83280> (entity: User; id: 0xda7c4f0 <x-coredata://5251395C-DDDC-424C-9372-EA8D883E0AE6/User/p1> ; data: {
    firstName = Lois;
    lastName = Lane;
    userid = "lois.lane";
})
2014-07-27 06:01:03.205 App[24030:3d07] ***** Thread BEFORE main_queue: <NSThread: 0xd6b2750>{name = (null), num = 4}
2014-07-27 06:01:03.205 App[24030:3d07] User Context <NSManagedObjectContext: 0xdb9a380>
2014-07-27 06:01:03.206 App[24030:3d07] NewUser <User: 0xd97fc00> (entity: User; id: 0xd97a510 <x-coredata://5251395C-DDDC-424C-9372-EA8D883E0AE6/User/p2> ; data: {
    firstName = Lois;
    lastName = Lane;
    userid = "lois.lane";
})

2014-07-27 06:01:03.207 App[24030:60b] ***** Thread AFTER main_queue: <NSThread: 0xdf80f80>{name = (null), num = 1}
2014-07-27 06:01:03.207 App[24030:60b] User Context (null)
2014-07-27 06:01:03.207 App[24030:3d07] ***** Thread BEFORE main_queue: <NSThread: 0xd6b2750>{name = (null), num = 4}
2014-07-27 06:01:03.208 App[24030:60b] NewUser <User: 0xda83280> (entity: User; id: 0xda7c4f0 <x-coredata://5251395C-DDDC-424C-9372-EA8D883E0AE6/User/p1> ; data: <fault>)
2014-07-27 06:01:03.208 App[24030:3d07] User Context <NSManagedObjectContext: 0xdb9a380>
(lldb)
```

The App crashes here as I try to access property in the object that do no exist.  I think the problem is in the treads?

**UPDATE 2**

```
- (void)didFinishFindingUser:(NSString*)user withResults:(NSArray*)results
{
    NSManagedObjectID *recordObjectID;
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if (results.count > 0)
    {
        self.inviteUser = (User*)[results firstObject];
        recordObjectID = self.inviteUser.objectID;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSManagedObjectContext *bgndContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
            bgndContext = self.objectManager.managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
            bgndContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = appDelegate.managedObjectStore.persistentStoreCoordinator;
            NSError * error = nil;
            self.inviteUser = (User *) [bgndContext existingObjectWithID:recordObjectID error:&error];
            NSLog(@"***** Thread AFTER main_queue: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
            NSLog(@"inviteUser Context %@", [self.inviteUser managedObjectContext]);
            NSLog(@"inviteUser %@", self.inviteUser);
            [self setNameForUser:self.inviteUser];
        });
    }
}
```

**LOG:**

```
2014-07-27 06:53:28.390 App[27898:60b] inviteUser Context (null)
2014-07-27 06:53:28.390 App[27898:60b] inviteUser (null)
```

Comment: As you can't get the managed object context this shouldn't be a fault issue. You should log the user object and the contents of results directly. How are you making the request and calling did finish method?

Comment: Thanks.  I did an update.  Let me know if you still want to see the finish method.

Comment: Yes. Why are you switching threads yourself? You need to be very careful with core data contexts and threads. Never pass managed objects between threads.

Comment: Under Update, you can see the codes.  I'm getting the main_queue to update the UI.  Fetching was done in the background thread.  I also added Update 2, when I'm trying to change threads, but now I'm getting (null).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below to get the appropriate object in the main thread context:

```
recordObjectID = self.inviteUser.objectID;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSManagedObjectContext *moc = self.objectManager.managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;;
        NSError * error = nil;

        self.inviteUser = (User *) [moc existingObjectWithID:recordObjectID error:&error];

        NSLog(@"***** Thread AFTER main_queue: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);
        NSLog(@"inviteUser Context %@", [self.inviteUser managedObjectContext]);
        NSLog(@"inviteUser %@", self.inviteUser);
        [self setNameForUser:self.inviteUser];
    });
```

Note however that setting `self.inviteUser` both on a background thread and to a background managed object is a bad idea. You should instead return only managed object ids from the background thread.

Also, if you have an object manager then you should try to use a method that gets your data in the background and does the switch to the main thread for you (I.e. Not use an operation directly if you can help it).

Comment: Thanks.  This still shows it as null.  I think I'm going change strategy.  The reason I took this route is b/c I get W `restkit.core_data:RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource.m:243 Performing managed object mapping with a nil managed object cache:
Unable to update existing object instances by identification attributes. Duplicate objects may be created. error.`

I'll start a new ticket for that and mark this answer correct.

Comment: Here is the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24985937/reskit-duplicate-objects-are-created

Answer (score 0):

Your object's managed object context is `nil`, this is why the faults cannot be fired. Make sure you check for all attributes and the context when you obtain the user object.

RestKit has many problems like this when it comes to multi-threading. In view of your copious code just to set up the "Object Manager", have you considered using plain Core Data and `NSURLSession`?